# Can I process a Click Event on a asp:Chart control using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm displaying a chart with appropriate data.  I'd like to be able to display detail data if the user clicks on the chart.  But, I can't seem to figure out how to get a button-click event to fire back to the code-behind.  I'm using vb.net.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

asp code:

```
<asp:Chart ID="ChartSalesA" runat="server" Width="350px" Height="250px" 
        OnClick="Chart_Click"
        ToolTip="Previous 5 Weeks" BorderlineColor="Transparent"> 
    <Titles>
        <asp:Title Font="Calibri, 11pt, style=Bold" Name="Title1" Text="Previous 5 Weeks">
        </asp:Title>
    </Titles>
    <Legends>
        <asp:Legend Name="Default" Alignment="Center" BackColor="Lavender" BorderColor="Black" Docking="Bottom" LegendStyle="Row"> 
        </asp:Legend> 
    </Legends>
    <Series> 
        <asp:Series ChartType="Column" ChartArea="MainChartArea" Name="Series1" Color="#9955ff" Legend="Default" LegendText="Sales" XAxisType="Primary"></asp:Series>
        <asp:Series ChartType="Line" ChartArea="MainChartArea" Name="Series2" YAxisType="Secondary" Legend="Default" Color="#99ccff" Enabled="True" LegendText="Customers" LabelBorderWidth="1" BorderWidth="3"></asp:Series>  
    </Series> 
    <ChartAreas> 
        <asp:ChartArea Name="MainChartArea" Area3DStyle-Enable3D="false">
            <AxisY Title="Weekly Sales"><LabelStyle Font="Calibri, 8pt" /></AxisY>
            <AxisY2 Title="Weekly Customers" ><LabelStyle Font="Calibri, 8pt" /></AxisY2>
            <AxisX Interval="1" IntervalType ="Weeks" IntervalAutoMode = "FixedCount"  ><LabelStyle Font="Calibri, 8pt" /></AxisX>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas> 
</asp:Chart>
```

code-behind:

```
Protected Sub Chart_Click() Handles ChartSalesA.Click
    'do something here when user clicks chart

    Dim x As Int16 = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Post your code, markup and code-behind.

Comment: added code, but there's really nothing in the vb code yet, until I can at least get something back...I just have a breakpoint on the x=0 for now.

Comment: Check this article: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102809-1.aspx to create clickable charts

Comment: So does the `Chart_Click()` method not fire? Have you put a break point in it to see if it gets to the line `Dim x As Int16 = 0`?

Comment: correct ... never gets to the breakpoint.  I thought it should be that easy, but it's not getting there. It's not posting back at all.

Comment: thanks @YuriyGalanter ... will read through that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `XValueMember="yourValueORID" PostBackValue="#VALX"` in your aspx part, to the series for which you want to postback to code behind and perform any operation. `yourValueORID` would be any column from the datasource you are binding to the chart.

Then modify your click event signature as below.

```
Protected Sub Chart_Click(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e) Handles ChartSalesA.Click

    'You will get your value from the XValueMember as below.
    Dim x As String = Convert.ToString(e.PostBackValue)        

End Sub
```

You can also do the same with `YValueMember="yourValueORID" PostBackValue="#VALY"`, if you want to pass your YValueMember to the code behind.

Comment: Thanks, @Devraj Gadhavi, this helped. I also needed to add 'autopostback="true" to the asp:Chart

Comment: for me the problem was I was creating the series in code and the OnClick event wasnt firing..  The fix was to set the PostBackValue property of the series